# VkKeyScanEx fails for german Keyboard layout

Tags: c++, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have a custom file which stores a list of German umlauts ("ä" "ö" )
My program needs to read these letters and print an ascii value.

I have tried this

```
key = (WORD) VkKeyScanEx((TCHAR) szLetterName[0], ::GetKeyboardLayout(0));
```

This piece of code always returns 65535 for all the german letters but gives a proper value for English Alphabets.

Any idea why this issue is coming. Any suggestions to fix this issue ??

Comment: Ugh, no, you are reading a text file.  Not a keyboard.  If you are lucky, this file is encoded with one of the Unicode encodings, like utf-8.  And has a BOM that indicates which encoding is used.  Unicode is not something that the C++ standard tries to tackle, you need a library.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** ASCII values for those character (see eg the ASCII table in http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange). Therefore you must use a different encoding (latin/UTF). Note that some of these encoding use multi-byte characters.

Comment: Is there anyway i can retrieve the scan codes for these letters